# Query Firebase using Rest Call

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I am querying firestore using query
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/mycollection

I am getting following Json. Can someone please help me how can I filter my query based on Rate field. I am writing following query and it doesn't work

[https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/mycolletion?Rate="15"](https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/mycolletion?Rate=%2215%22)

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "name": "0C45nDuozgQDOwEx5xHR",
      "fields": {
        "Clinic": {
          "stringValue": "American Hospital"
        },
        "Rate": {
          "stringValue": "140"
        },
     ,`enter code here`
      "createTime": "2020-06-28T20:32:18.776123Z",
      "updateTime": "2020-07-22T21:19:24.061647Z"
    },
    
    {
      "name": "Jm3tNVWmk4Q1pk87KL1m",
      "fields": {
        "Clinic": {
          "stringValue": "Cleaveland clinic"
        },
      "Rate": {
          "stringValue": "150"
        },
      "createTime": "2020-06-28T20:28:03.726819Z",
      "updateTime": "2020-07-22T21:19:05.073019Z"
    }
 }
```

Comment: Seems like you'll want to learn to use the list request.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/list

Comment: Can someone please write an example  url how can I filter data based on Rate field.

Comment: Hello @ZaraKhan, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you share the code you are using to get that output? Also, take a look and follow the instructions in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your question easier for the community to help you.

Comment: Hi Rafael. There is no code I am only calling a rest service from postman or from browser   https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/mycollection

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Rate` field is an object (inside another object to make it worse), so in order to achieve that you would either need to update you Firestore structure to do it all in the request URL, or you would have to use a structured query in the body of the request.

- Change the structure:

In order to work with the request you already have, you will need to change the structure to (using the 1st document as an example):

```
{
  "name": "0C45nDuozgQDOwEx5xHR",
  "Clinic": "American Hospital",
  "Rate": "140",
  "createTime": "2020-06-28T20:32:18.776123Z",
  "updateTime": "2020-07-22T21:19:24.061647Z"
}
```

which in my opinion makes it simpler although I don't have the full picture

- Have a Structured query in your request body:

To keep the structure you already have you will need to use thisURL:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/:runQuery
```

And add this to the body of the request:

```
"structuredQuery": {
    "from": [{
        "collectionId": "mycollection"
    }],
    "where": {
        "fieldFilter": {
            "fields": {
                "Rate": {
                    "stringValue": "15"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can check more details by checking the [runQuery Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery) and the [structuredQuery Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery) for what else you can do with these options.